# In Stripe Android CardWidget How to change hint text size and hint text?

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I m using Stripe library stripe-android:6.1.2.
I have integrated Stripe provide Card widget for android.
It's very clumsy. Card number overlaps MM/YYYY etc. Also textSize is large. Want to make it Small.
Need help in customising these attributes.

Comment: post some code for any1 to see the issue

Answer (score 5):

As per the Stripe doc: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android

You can try:

```
<style name="CardWidgetStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:background">#0000FF</item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/EditTextOverride</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextOverride</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextOverride" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Then in your layout file, apply the style to the CardInputWidget to change its text, text hint, and background colors.

```
<com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget
    android:id="@+id/card_input_widget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/CardWidgetStyle"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy you just saved my time :)

Answer (score 3):

Stripe CardInputWidget documentation says here:

https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/

> The individual EditText views of this widget can be styled by defining a style Stripe.CardInputWidget.EditText that extends Stripe.Base.CardInputWidget.EditText.

I created a style:

```
<style name="Stripe.CardInputWidget.EditText" parent="Stripe.Base.CardInputWidget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#808080</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
</style>
```

and applied it to the widget

```
<com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget
        android:id="@+id/cardInputWidget"
        style="@style/Stripe.CardInputWidget.EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_box_blue_line"
        android:padding="5dp">
</com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget>
```

Answer (score 2):

For **hint text** If you implemented stripe version above ***10.4.0*** you may use **setCardHint()** works for both  **CardMultilineWidget** and **CardInputWidget**, otherwise for **CardInputWidget** you can add one of the following attributes in your resource file

- stripe:cardHintText="xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx"
- app:cardHintText="xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx"

Answer (score 0):

for CardMultilineWidget if you want to change the hintTextSize
Go to your base theme and add

```
<item name="android:textSize">14sp</item> //use your preferred hint size
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

style.xml

```
<style name="CardTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/grey</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/white</item>
 </style>
```

activity_card.xml

```
<com.stripe.android.view.CardMultilineWidget
        android:id="@+id/card_widget"
        android:theme="@style/CardTheme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```