# PlaceHolder missing in real device in Stripe Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments

Hey I am using [stripe](https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/) in my application. The problem is **placeholder/hint** is missing. I don't understand why is causing in real device. In emulator is working fine. I tried some code which is working in emulator device and it's not working in real device. Can someone guide me please. Thanks

**In real device**

[image]

**In emulator device**

[image]

**build.gradle**

```
implementation "com.stripe:stripe-android:19.0.0"
```

**activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.stripe.android.view.CardMultilineWidget
        android:id="@+id/cardWidget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CardWidgetStyle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:shouldShowPostalCode="false" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**style.kt**

```
<style name="AppTheme.CardWidgetStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/source_sans_pro</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/smoke</item>
</style>
```

**StripeFactory.kt**

```
class StripeFactory {
    private lateinit var stripe: Stripe
  
    suspend fun getStripe(): Stripe {
        if (!this::stripe.isInitialized) {
            val stripeKey = getStripeKey()
            stripe = Stripe(appContext, stripeKey)
            initializeStripe(stripeKey)
        }
        return stripe
    }

    private fun initializeStripe(publishableKey: String) {
        PaymentConfiguration.init(
            context = appContext,
            publishableKey = publishableKey
        )
    }

    private suspend fun getStripeKey(): String {
        return getKey()
    }

    suspend fun getGooglePayConfig(): GooglePayConfig {
        return GooglePayConfig(getStripeKey())
    }
}
```

**viewmodel.kt**

```
fun createCardPaymentMethod(fragment: Fragment? = null, cardParams: CardParams) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            stripeFactory.getStripe().createPaymentMethod(
                paymentMethodCreateParams = PaymentMethodCreateParams.createCard(cardParams),
                callback = object : ApiResultCallback<PaymentMethod> {
                    override fun onSuccess(result: PaymentMethod) {

                    }
                    override fun onError(e: Exception) {
                        Log.e(e, "Stripe create token error"+ e)

                    }
                })
        }
}
```

**UPDATE** I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51796638) as well is not working.

```
<style name="CardWidgetStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:background">#0000FF</item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/EditTextOverride</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextOverride</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextOverride" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try running your application in a few devices and check if it's a device specific problem?

And you might also want to check your global theme and see if there's a global color setting for textHint.

Comment: no. Its not device sepcific questions. Its working till `18.0.0` if I update `18.0.1` it starting causing in placeholder

Comment: How about using the latest SDK version 19.1.0? If the problem still happens after integrating the latest SDK, you might want to file an issue and let Stripe team know. https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues

Comment: @qichan I already bug the issuue.